# Robot Framework - How to verify a media file has been requested upon user interaction

Tags: python, robotframework

I apologize if this is a simple answer but I'm fairly new to robot framework and python.

I'm trying to find out if there's a way to verify an .mp3 file has been requested and gives a 200 response when a user interacts with the system.  I am running robot framework with the `Selenium2Library` and python 3.6.

I've been trying to use the `RequestsLibrary` library but I've found it isn't testing the user interaction.  Using the "Get Requests" keyword I have:

```
Get Requests
   Create Session   chimeFile   base URL
   ${resp}=    Get Request   chimeFile   path/to/media/file/on/server
   Should Be Equal As Strings   ${resp.status_code}   200
   Log   ${resp.headers}
```

This results in a pass.  The `Log` keyword correctly shows me the information related to the request but I have not been able to find a way to grab that information.  The problem is, this isn't testing the result from the user interaction and only tests the server call.  I need to know if when the user receives a message, the chime file is successfully requested with a 200 response.

I've also looked into possibly using the test browser's cache to find the file after the user has gone through the interaction using the `OperatingSystem` library.  That has resulted in deciphering the cache file and I don't know if that will provide a solution.

I've also found https://github.com/s4int/robotframework-BrowserMobProxyLibrary recently but am not sure it would be a solution since I'm not very familiar with how to set up the proxy.  Before I spend time researching this I want to make sure there isn't a better solution.

My question is whether or not there is a way to use robot framework or if there is a library which will allow access to the network tab in Chrome without making a separate call to the server.  If there isn't a solution using robot framework, is there another language I should use to grab the request upon successful user interaction?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Short answer (and not solving your case, thus - comment) - nope, you can't do that. RF's `Selenium2Library` is a (very nice)  wrapper over Selenium, which is a webserver protocol implementation, which does not allow interaction on such low level as the network; it is targeted only on DOM interaction. There are two possible solutions though - you already went to the 1st, browsermob to intercept any browser <-> server communication (MiM yourself :).

Comment: The other is to set the browser's profile to automatically save resources with the mime type the mp3 is send with, and verifying the file is downloaded. This is again suboptimal - the mp3 has to be available as a link (not embedded in the html), plus this will hardly work on a remote browser (you can't (easily) check the file on a remote machine's file system).

Comment: Autocorrect strikes again - in my first comment, please read "... over Selenium, which is a **WebDriver** protocol implementation, which ..."

Comment: Thanks Todor for the information.  Eventually, I might be able to implement the browsermob library with some more work on figuring out how to use proxy servers with automation.  I will be able to use the suggestion of storing the file locally for now, though, since all testing is currently being done on a local computer.